# set the color of categories in venn diagram in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, venn

I am using ggVennDiagram to creat a venn diagram. I would like to set the color of categories manually. Here is what I am trying, however the color of border line of the circles is not changed.

```
x <- list(A=1:5,B=2:7,C=3:6,D=4:9)
ggVennDiagram(x, label = "count", label_alpha = 0, 
          color =  c("A" = "yellow","B" ="steelblue",'C' = 'red', 'D' = 'black') ,
          set_color = c("A" = "yellow","B" ="steelblue", 'C' = 'red', 'D' = 'black')) +
 scale_fill_gradient(low = "#F4FAFE", high = "#4981BF")
```

Any Idea how I can match the colors of circle lines with the name of categories?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `ggVennDiagram` documentation it looks as if you have to build up the venn diagram rather than use the `ggVennDiagram` function. Maybe this adaptation from the documentation example gives you enough to work on...

Updated to include OP's comment for percentage count.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggVennDiagram)

x <- list(A=1:5,B=2:7,C=3:6,D=4:9)

venn <- Venn(x)
data <- process_data(venn)
ggplot() +
  # 1. region count layer
  geom_sf(aes(fill = count), data = venn_region(data)) +
  # 2. set edge layer
  geom_sf(aes(color = name), data = venn_setedge(data), show.legend = TRUE, size = 2) +
  # 3. set label layer
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name), data = venn_setlabel(data)) +
  # 4. region label layer
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = paste0(count, " (", scales::percent(count/sum(count), accuracy = 2), ")")), 
                data = venn_region(data),
                size = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#F4FAFE", high = "#4981BF")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "yellow","B" ="steelblue",'C' = 'red', 'D' = 'black'),
                     labels = c('D' = 'D = bdiv_human'))+
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This looks good. Do. you know how I can add fraction (percentage) of the intersections to the plot as well.

Comment: actually having both number and percentage printed on plot.

Comment: I think that does it.

Answer (score 1):

The `ggVennDiagram` command calls the `ggVennDiagram::plot_venn` function for plotting colored areas. You can modify this function according to your needs.
See below my suggestion.

```
plot_venn <- function (x, show_intersect, set_color, set_size, label, label_geom, 
    label_alpha, label_color, label_size, label_percent_digit, 
    label_txtWidth, edge_lty, edge_size, ...)  {
    venn <- Venn(x)
    data <- process_data(venn)
    p <- ggplot() + geom_sf(aes_string(fill = "count"), data = data@region) + 
        geom_sf(aes_string(color = "name"), data = data@setEdge, 
            show.legend = F, lty = edge_lty, size = edge_size, color = set_color) + 
        geom_sf_text(aes_string(label = "name"), data = data@setLabel, 
            size = set_size, color = set_color) + theme_void()
    if (label != "none" & show_intersect == FALSE) {
        region_label <- data@region %>% dplyr::filter(.data$component == 
            "region") %>% dplyr::mutate(percent = paste(round(.data$count * 
            100/sum(.data$count), digits = label_percent_digit), 
            "%", sep = "")) %>% dplyr::mutate(both = paste(.data$count, 
            paste0("(", .data$percent, ")"), sep = "\n"))
        if (label_geom == "label") {
            p <- p + geom_sf_label(aes_string(label = label), 
                data = region_label, alpha = label_alpha, color = label_color, 
                size = label_size, lineheight = 0.85, label.size = NA)
        }
        if (label_geom == "text") {
            p <- p + geom_sf_text(aes_string(label = label), 
                data = region_label, alpha = label_alpha, color = label_color, 
                size = label_size, lineheight = 0.85)
        }
    }
    if (show_intersect == TRUE) {
        items <- data@region %>% dplyr::rowwise() %>% dplyr::mutate(text = stringr::str_wrap(paste0(.data$item, 
            collapse = " "), width = label_txtWidth)) %>% sf::st_as_sf()
        label_coord = sf::st_centroid(items$geometry) %>% sf::st_coordinates()
        p <- ggplot(items) + geom_sf(aes_string(fill = "count")) + 
            geom_sf_text(aes_string(label = "name"), data = data@setLabel, 
                inherit.aes = F) + geom_text(aes_string(label = "count", 
            text = "text"), x = label_coord[, 1], y = label_coord[, 
            2], show.legend = FALSE) + theme_void()
        ax <- list(showline = FALSE)
        p <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text")) %>% plotly::layout(xaxis = ax, 
            yaxis = ax)
    }
    p
}
```

Then, you can run the code:

```
library(ggVennDiagram)
library(ggplot2)

# Replace the plot_venn function with the modified version
assignInNamespace(x="plot_venn", value=plot_venn, ns="ggVennDiagram")  

x <- list(A=1:5,B=2:7,C=3:6,D=4:9)
ggVennDiagram(x, label = "count", label_alpha = 0, 
          color =  c("A" = "yellow","B" ="steelblue",'C' = 'red', 'bdiv_human' = 'black') ,
          set_color = c("A" = "yellow","B" ="steelblue", 'C' = 'red', 'bdiv_human' = 'black')) +
 scale_fill_gradient(low = "#F4FAFE", high = "#4981BF") +
 scale_color_gradient(low = "#F4FAFE", high = "#4981BF")
```

[image]